# Java character encoding discrepancies on Gitlab

Tags: java, character-encoding, localization, gitlab, locale

I'm seeing the behavior where my code running locally produces characters different from when it's running in the Gitlab staging pipeline triggering the associated failure of the tests.  Specifically,

Here's the output I'm seeing in my local environment:
[image]

and here's the one from staging:

[image]

looks like tests on the staging box are misinterpreting the `$` formatting somehow, and the `$` character gets replaced with  `¤`

Here's the associated Java code, I'm obtaining the default locale to formulate the message:

```
return new String[] { headerLine.toString(),
                "Date: " + tx.getTransactionDate().getDate().toString() + "\nAmount: "

                        + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.getDefault()).format(tx.getAmount()) + "\nAccount: "
                        + (accumulatedInputs.get(FIELD_ACTNUM) != null
                                ? accumulatedInputs.get(FIELD_ACTNUM).value
                                : accumulatedInputs.get(TransactionInquiryIntentProcessor.FIELD_REFNUM).value)
                        + "\n" + subTitleBuilder.toString() };
```

Not sure what could be wrong in that staging environment?

Comment: what are the respective default Locales, that is, result from `Locale.getDefault()`? if they are the same, see next comment

Comment: I would guess, I never checked, that the encoding could depends of the locale. _It make sense, you won't be able to print Japanese using a ISO-8859-15_. So both environnement are using different encoding, or more precisely, different locale.

Comment: Unfortunately, at this point I don't have physical access to that machine where it's failing, and yes, the default locale seems to be the prime suspect, but aside from confirming it via a `System.out.println` or something what are my options in changing it on that Gitlab machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up having our DevOps team explicitly specifying `en_US` locale in Kubernetes which fixed the issue.